# Unable to download plugin(s). Please try again openfire

Tags: openfire

I'm not able to add plugin in openfire, i added manually but still showing unable to upload
I also copy to openfire/plugins folder .jar file but still not showing plugins in openfire admin panel
Getting this error

```
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:349)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:441)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:936)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:801)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:224)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:51)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:586)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:44)
at   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:598)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:533)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: [host-name]
at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(Unknown Source)
at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(Unknown Source)
at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:250)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:306)
... 60 more
 2015.04.04 17:22:07 org.jivesoftware.util.log.util.CommonsLogFactory - Prototype
 com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor13.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:409)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1127)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:356)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2502)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2539)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2321)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:832)
at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:46)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor11.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:409)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:417)
at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:344)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at org.logicalcobwebs.proxool.DefaultConnectionBuilder.buildConnection(DefaultConnectionBuilder.java:39)
at org.logicalcobwebs.proxool.Prototyper.buildConnection(Prototyper.java:159)
at org.logicalcobwebs.proxool.Prototyper.sweep(Prototyper.java:102)
at org.logicalcobwebs.proxool.PrototyperThread.run(PrototyperThread.java:44)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: [host-name]
at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(Unknown Source)
at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(Unknown Source)
at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:250)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:306)
```

Answer (score 2):

I was working with local server, so everyday i have to start open fire for start chat.
so just open openfire with admin permission
means run as admin after that this problem will not arise